# Conditional Fields Presentation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zfdatagrid

I have a table with 4 field named as `Rowid`,`Customermainid`,`company`,`email`.

I wanna add class attribute to the particular row which satisfies the following condition `Rowid > 28` for differentiate them

I have searched a lot and get `$grid->setClassRowCondition("{{Rowid}} > 28","green");` from [here](https://code.google.com/p/zfdatagrid/wiki/Bvb_Grid_Deploy_Table)

But it doesn't work for me. What am i doing wrong with this code? Help me guys!

**EDIT**

I have found the reason for my question.

The given link works well only for the grid which is loaded by `Bvb_Grid_Deploy_Table` class.

But i have load my grid with the use of `Bvb_Grid_Deploy_JqGrid` class.

So only it doesn't work.

I found only the reason, not an answer.

I have found one more option

```
$grid->updateColumn('field',array('hRow'=>true));
```

This also doesn't work.

If anybody know the answer,guide me guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I have found the solution of my problem. I have add the following code to `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` file

```
va=srvr[0];
if(va>28)
 {
  return'<td role="gridcell" class="test" '+prp+' title="'+$.jgrid.stripHtml(v)+'">'+v+"</td>"
 }
else
 {
  return'<td role="gridcell" '+prp+' title="'+$.jgrid.stripHtml(v)+'">'+v+"</td>"
 }
```

In the above code `srvr` contain whole row value. `srvr[0]` have rowid value

Answer (score 0):

you can try this-

```
if($var>28) {echo "<tr whatever the style you want>"; echo "<td>".$var."</td></tr>";}
```

I think this will solve your problem.